# Checking whether there is a subset of size k of an array which has a sum multiple of n

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Good evening, I have an array in java with `n` integer numbers. I want to check if there is a subset of size *k* of the entries that satisfies the condition:

The sum of those *k* entries is a multiple of *m*.

How may I do this as efficiently as possible? There are `n!/k!(n-k)!` subsets that I need to check.

Comment: How large is m, n and k?

Comment: In my particular case m=n and k=m/2. m is under ten thousand.

Comment: @matt I haven't really started yet, I thought this might be something that is done often.

Comment: It certainly does seem like it would be (or at least something close to it). I need to put my thinking cap on.

Comment: I mean, I know how to check if a number is a multiple or not, what I need is a problem that can sort through each of the subsets of size k.

Comment: Numbers can be negative right?

Comment: yes. Although my real trouble is finding all the subsets of size k.

Comment: With n = 10k and k = 5k, number of subsets of size `k` is 10^3000. Are you OK with that? I will take years to find an answer in the worst case.

Comment: @ModdedBear what's wrong with finding all subsets of size k ?

Comment: @mangusta there's nothing wrong with it other than the fact that I can't do it.

Comment: @mostruash I'm not terribly happy, but I do want to find a way to sort through the subsets of that size, mabye there is a ways so that you don't have to check all of the subsets in this particular problem. But I am in need of a way to find all of the subsets of a given size in general.

Comment: Note that you are not trying to find ALL subsets, just the ONE that satisfies your condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic programming. The state is (prefix length, sum modulo m, number of elements in a subset). Transitions are obvious: we either add one more number(increasing the number of elements in a subset and computing new sum modulo m), or we just increase prefix lenght(not adding the current number). If you just need a yes/no answer, you can store only the last layer of values and apply bit optimizations to compute transitions faster. The time complexity is O(n * m * k), or about n * m * k / 64 operations with bit optimizations. The space complexity is O(m * k). It looks feasible for a few thousands of elements. By bit optimizations I mean using things like bitset in C++ that can perform an operation on a group of bits at the same time using bitwise operations.

Comment: sorry, I got lost, are you saying I should check each subset and check if it has k elements? Or how do we make sure we only get subsets with k elements?

Comment: @ILoveCoding i think the space complexity in case of yes/no answer, is O(m*n), because we need modulos for all prefixes with sizes from at least k, up to n, i.e. that k-sized subset might be within k-sized prefix, k+1-sized prefix, .., n-1-sized prefix, and finally n-sized prefix

Comment: Took me almost a year,  but I finally understand it !

Answer (score 0):

I don't like this solution, but it may work for your needs

```
public boolean containsSubset( int[] a , int currentIndex, int currentSum, int depth, int divsor, int maxDepth){

    //you could make a, maxDepth, and divisor static as well


    //If maxDepthis equal to depth, then our subset has k elements, in addition the sum of
    //elements must be divisible by out divsor, m
    //If this condition is satisafied, then there exists a subset of size k whose sum is divisible by m
    if(depth==maxDepth&&currentSum%divsor==0) 
         return true;

    //If the depth is greater than or equal maxDepth, our subset has more than k elements, thus
    //adding more elements can not satisfy the necessary conditions
    //additionally we know that if it contains k elements and is divisible by m, it would've satisafied the above condition. 
    if(depth>=maxdepth)
         return false;


    //boolean to be returned, initialized to false because we have not found any sets yet
    boolean ret = false;

    //iterate through all remaining elements of our array 
    for (int i = currentIndex+1; i < a.length; i++){
    //this may be an optimization or this line
    //for (int i = currentIndex+1; i < a.length-maxDepth+depth; i++){



         //by recursing, we add a[i] to our set we then use an or operation on all our subsets that could 
         //be constructed from the numbers we have so far so that if any of them satisfy our condition (return true) 
         //then the value of the variable ret will be true
         ret |= containsSubset(a,i,currentSum+a[i],depth+1,divisor, maxDepth);

    } //end for


    //return the variable storing whether any sets of numbers that could be constructed from the numbers so far.
    return ret;

}
```

Then invoke this method as such

```
 //this invokes our method with "no numbers added to our subset so far" so it will try adding 
 // all combinations of other elements to determine if the condition is satisfied.
 boolean answer = containsSubset(myArray,-1,0,0,m,k);
```

EDIT:

<strike>You could probably optimize this by taking everything modulo (%) m and deleting repeats. For examples with large values of n and/or k, but small values of m, this could be a pretty big optimization.</strike>

EDIT 2:

The above optimization I listed isn't helpful. You may need the repeats to get the correct information. My bad.

Happy Coding! Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: I'm still reading, but I want to take repeats into account. It'll take me at least 5 minutes to understand.

Comment: I added code comments. They might be a little much, but they really should help.

Comment: Thanks, the only reason I haven't upvoted yet is that I haven't processed it yet.

Comment: Take your time. I use this recursive method + recursion depth approach for a lot of problems with subsets. It might not be the most elegant, but it should work. Unfortunately it will probably check all     n!/k!(n-k)! sets (though it may be required to)

Comment: yeah, my main question was sorting through all subsets, mabye there are better heuristics for this particular problem.

Comment: So effectively in the code I posted, going one level deeper in recursion adds one element to your subset. Then the current index variable takes care of checking certain combinations twice (which is undesirable)

Comment: I'm sorry if this is dumb but won't the program check for one subset of size k and if it doesnt work  try checking for a subsets of k and then return false?

Comment: @Modded Bear, Actually it does do that so it isn't dumb, but the function will kill any sets of size k+1. However, if this too much for the program to handle, I'm sure there is a conditional branch that can satisfy this (such as not going to the loop if (depth == maxDepth)

Answer (score 0):

If numbers have lower and upper bounds, it might be better to:

1. Iterate all `multiple`s of `n` where `lower_bound * k < multiple < upper_bound * k`
2. Check if there is a subset with sum `multiple` in the array (see [Subset Sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)) using dynamic programming.

Complexity is `O(k^2 * (lower_bound + upper_bound)^2)`. This approach can be optimized further, I believe with careful thinking.

Otherwise you can find all subsets of size `k`. Complexity is `O(n!)`. Using backtracking (pseudocode-ish):

```
function find_subsets(array, k, index, current_subset):
  if current_subset.size = k:
    add current_subset to your solutions list
    return

  if index = array.size:
    return

  number := array[index]
  add number to current_subset
  find_subsets(array, k, index + 1, current_subset)
  remove number from current_subset
  find_subsets(array, k, index + 1, current_subset)
```